# C++ how to parse a ppm file?

Tags: c++, parsing, ppm

I'm trying to parse a ppm file.

The spec is this: http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html

Example:

```
P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
 0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0   15  0 15
 0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0    0  0  0
 0  0  0    0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0
15  0 15    0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0
```

The stuff after the "15" are the rgb values of all pixels in the give image.

I have tried this so far:

```
void read_and_draw_ppm_file() {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(TEXTURE_FILE.c_str());
    string line;
    int count = 0;
    while (getline(infile, line) && count < 4) {
        count++;
    }


    char c;

    int red = -1, green = -1, blue = -1;
    int rgb_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_WIDTH; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < TEXTURE_HEIGHT; j++) {


              infile >> c;


            if (rgb_count == 0) {
                if (red != -1 && blue != -1 && green != -1) {
                    cout << red<<endl;
                    cout << green<<endl;
                    cout << blue<<endl;


                    uint32_t colour = (255 << 24) + (int(red) << 16) + (int(green) << 8) + int(blue);
                    window.setPixelColour(i, j, colour);

                     red = -1;
                    blue = -1;
                    green = -1;
                }
                red = (int) (unsigned char) c;
                rgb_count++;

            } else if (rgb_count == 1) {
                green = (int) (unsigned char) c;
                rgb_count++;
            } else if (rgb_count == 2) {
                blue = (int) (unsigned char) c;
                rgb_count = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    infile.close();
}
```

The idea is to basically extract triplets of 3 bytes, then convert each to rgb respectively.

Problem is, when I display the image into the screen, the image isn't quite the same as it's supposed to be.

Where am I going wrong?

The original image:

[image]

Rendered Image[image] image:

Comment: _isn't quite the same as it's supposed to be_: can you elaborate on what's wrong with the image?  Also, you're reading your input file as characters, not numbers.

Comment: edited with the expected output/actual output

Comment: you can do less things at once, if you read the ppm file, write the same back to a second file and then use some existing software to view the image. That way you can find out if the problem is in reading the file or in displaying the image

Comment: this line `red = (int) (unsigned char) c;` will give you ASCII code. replace it with `red = c - '0'`. Also, think how to handle digits like `15`. You are reading character by character.

Comment: I have tried reading like so: `infile >> c`; My  output imqge still doesn't match the expected ouput

Answer (score 1):

You read in a value for `red`, then increment `j`.  Then you read in `green`, and increment `j`.  Next you read `blue`, store the pixel value, and increment `j`.

So you're writing out your values spaced out every 3 rows.

Comment: I have reset the values or `red`, `green` and `blue`...the output image still doesn't match the expected image

Comment: @nz_21 You're only changing the pixel color in your window of every 3rd pixel. Only when j%3 == 0 (except for when j == 0).

Comment: Yup, not sure I understand why that's wrong. I update the pixel colors only after having seen 3 pixels (rgb)